# Matplotlib radar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples

so I was experimenting with [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html) matplotlib example. In the data part I tried to make the graphic from a tuple like this:

```
data =    data[0:8]

f1_CO =   [0.88, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00] 
f1_O3 =   [0.89, 0.01, 0.07, 0.00, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.03] 
f1_both = [0.86, 0.01, 0.08, 0.00, 0.00, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01]
```

But it go wrong because it says:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

So, what do I have to change to make it possible to make a plot from a tuple?
The complete code is :

```
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes 
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection 
from pylab import *
import wave
import struct

def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='polygon'): 
     """Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes. 
     """ 
     # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles 
     theta = 2*pi * linspace(0, 1-1/int(num_vars), num_vars) 
     #print theta
     #print
     # rotate theta such that the first axis is at the top 
     theta += pi/2 

     def draw_poly_frame(self, x0, y0, r): 
         # TODO: should use transforms to convert (x, y) to (r, theta) 
         verts = [(r*cos(t) + x0, r*sin(t) + y0) for t in theta] 
         return Polygon(verts, closed=True) 

     def draw_circle_frame(self, x0, y0, r): 
         return Circle((x0, y0), r) 

     frame_dict = {'polygon': draw_poly_frame, 'circle': draw_circle_frame} 
     if frame not in frame_dict: 
         raise ValueError, 'unknown value for `frame`: %s' % frame 

     class RadarAxes(PolarAxes): 
         """Class for creating a radar chart (a.k.a. a spider or star chart) 

         http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart 
         """ 
         name = 'radar' 
         # use 1 line segment to connect specified points 
         RESOLUTION = 1
         # define draw_frame method 
         draw_frame = frame_dict[frame] 

         def fill(self, *args, **kwargs): 
             """Override fill so that line is closed by default""" 
             closed = kwargs.pop('closed', True) 
             return super(RadarAxes, self).fill(closed=closed, *args,**kwargs) 

         def plot(self, *args, **kwargs): 
             """Override plot so that line is closed by default""" 
             lines = super(RadarAxes, self).plot(*args, **kwargs) 
             for line in lines: 
                 self._close_line(line) 

         def _close_line(self, line): 
             x, y = line.get_data() 
             # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up 
             if x[0] != x[-1]: 
                 x = concatenate((x, [x[0]])) 
                 y = concatenate((y, [y[0]])) 
                 line.set_data(x, y) 

         def set_varlabels(self, labels, rvals, rlabels): 
             self.set_thetagrids(theta * 180/pi, labels) 
             self.set_rgrids(rvals, labels=rlabels, size='small')

         def get_axes_patch(self): 
             x0, y0 = (0.5, 0.5) 
             r = 0.5 
             return self.draw_frame(x0, y0, r)

     register_projection(RadarAxes) 
     return theta 


if __name__ == '__main__':


    w = wave.open('C:/Python27/demo1.wav','r')
    nf = w.getnframes()
    sw = w.getsampwidth()
    assert(sw==2)
    rf = w.readframes(nf)
    w.close()
    data = struct.unpack("%sh" %nf,rf)
    for i in range(9):
        print i,data[i]

    N = 9
    theta = radar_factory(N) 

    data =    data[0:8]
    f1_CO =   [0.88, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00] 
    f1_O3 =   [0.89, 0.01, 0.07, 0.00, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.03] 
    f1_both = [0.86, 0.01, 0.08, 0.00, 0.00, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01] 

    f2_base = [0.07, 0.95, 0.04, 0.05, 0.00, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00]
    f2_CO =   [0.08, 0.94, 0.04, 0.02, 0.00, 0.01, 0.12, 0.04, 0.00] 
    f2_O3 =   [0.07, 0.95, 0.05, 0.04, 0.00, 0.02, 0.12, 0.00, 0.00] 
    f2_both = [0.09, 0.95, 0.02, 0.03, 0.00, 0.01, 0.13, 0.06, 0.00] 

    f3_base = [0.01, 0.02, 0.85, 0.19, 0.05, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
    f3_CO =   [0.01, 0.01, 0.79, 0.10, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.31, 0.00] 
    f3_O3 =   [0.01, 0.02, 0.86, 0.27, 0.16, 0.19, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00] 
    f3_both = [0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.24, 0.13, 0.16, 0.00, 0.50, 0.00] 

    f4_base = [0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.74, 0.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
    f4_CO =   [0.00, 0.02, 0.03, 0.38, 0.31, 0.31, 0.00, 0.59, 0.00] 
    f4_O3 =   [0.01, 0.03, 0.00, 0.32, 0.29, 0.27, 0.00, 0.00, 0.95] 
    f4_both = [0.01, 0.03, 0.00, 0.28, 0.24, 0.23, 0.00, 0.44, 0.88] 

    f5_base = [0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.21, 0.12, 0.98, 0.00, 0.00]
    f5_CO =   [0.02, 0.02, 0.11, 0.47, 0.69, 0.58, 0.88, 0.00, 0.00] 
    f5_O3 =   [0.02, 0.00, 0.03, 0.37, 0.56, 0.47, 0.87, 0.00, 0.00] 
    f5_both = [0.02, 0.00, 0.18, 0.45, 0.64, 0.55, 0.86, 0.00, 0.16] 

    fig = figure(figsize=(9,9))
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.25, hspace=0.20)
    axlist = []
    axisNum = 0
    bases = [data, f2_base, f3_base, f5_base, f4_base]
    COs = [f1_CO, f2_CO, f3_CO, f4_CO, f5_CO]
    O3s = [f1_O3, f2_O3, f3_O3, f4_O3, f5_O3]
    boths = [f1_both, f2_both, f3_both, f4_both, f5_both]
    everything = [bases, COs, O3s, boths]
    titles = ['Muestreo 1', 'Muestreo 2', 'Muestreo 3', 'Muestreo 4']
    colors = ['b', 'r', 'g', 'm', 'y']
    for row in range(2):
        for col in range(2):
            axisNum += 1
            if axisNum == 2:
                 #Unfortunately, it looks like the loc keyword to legend() is 
                 #relative to a specific subplot, rather than the figure itself. 
                 #So, the positioning seen looks good, but if you resize the 
                 #figure to be larger the legend becomes obviously bound to a 
                 #specific subplot. This is in contrast to how the position works
                 #in something like figtext(). Had trouble using figlegend(), but
                 #need to try some more...
                legend(('Factor 1', 'Factor 2', 'Factor 3', 'Factor 4', 
                         'Factor 5'), loc=(0.95, 0.895), borderpad=0.01, 
                         shadow=False, prop=matplotlib.font_manager
                         .FontProperties(size='smaller'), markerscale=0.4)

            data = everything[axisNum-1]
            ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, axisNum, projection='radar')
            ax.set_title(titles[axisNum-1], weight='bold', size='medium', 
                          horizontalalignment='center', 
                          verticalalignment='center', 
                          position=(0.5, 1.1))
            p1 = ax.plot(theta, data[0], color=colors[0]) 
            p2 = ax.plot(theta, data[1], color=colors[1])
            p3 = ax.plot(theta, data[2], color=colors[2])
            p4 = ax.plot(theta, data[3], color=colors[3])
            p5 = ax.plot(theta, data[4], color=colors[4])
            ax.fill(theta, data[0], facecolor=colors[0])  
            ax.fill(theta, data[1], facecolor=colors[1]) 
            ax.fill(theta, data[2], facecolor=colors[2])     
            ax.fill(theta, data[3], facecolor=colors[3]) 
            ax.fill(theta, data[4], facecolor=colors[4]) 
             #axlist.extend(ax) #This does not work because ax is a 
                                #RadarAxesSubplot object, which is not iterable
            axlist.append(ax)  #append() works because it simply tacks on to 
                                #the list, as opposed to merging items from two
                                #lists
            for patch in ax.patches: 
                patch.set_alpha(0.25) 


    figtext(0.5, 0.965,  '5-Factor Solution Profiles Across Four Scenarios', ha='center', color='black', weight='bold', size='large')



     #Crudely plot the grid lines I want to see: normalized concentrations of
     #chemicals range from 0 to 1...
    radiiGrid = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
    theta_rgrid = radar_factory(100)
    for ax in axlist:
        for r in radiiGrid:
            radii = repeat(r, 100)
            ax.plot(theta_rgrid, radii, color='lightgrey')

     # FIXME: legend doesn't work when fill is called 
    spokeLabels = ['Sulfate', 'Nitrate', 'EC', 'OC1', 'OC2', 'OC3', 'OP',
 'CO', 
                    'O3']
    radiiLabels = [str(rg) for rg in radiiGrid]
    for ax in axlist:
        ax.set_varlabels(spokeLabels, radiiGrid, radiiLabels)

    show()
```

Comment: Can you reduce this down to the relevant section of code?  Most people are not willing to wade through that much code to fix what is a data-structure related problem.

Comment: Also, can you please paste in the _full_ backtrace of the exception?  It will tell you what line error originated from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from the tuple type.
It seems that data[0] (length = 9) and  theta (length = 8) haven't the same length (first dimension).

You have to put `data = data[0:9]`

Comment: Yeah, that was all!! I hadn't noticed that :P